# ContentPlaceHolder to HtmlString

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm moving my .Master code to partial views because we are including razor views in the project. 
We are using the partial views to mantain the .Master and the _Layout without duplicating code.

The _Layout looks something like this

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>@RenderSection("Title", required: false)</title>
   @RenderSection("Head", required: false)
   @{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/Partials/head.Master.cshtml"); }
   @RenderSection("HeadBottom", required: false)
</head>
<body @bodyClass id="@ViewData["bodyId"]">
   @{
      ViewData["renderBody"]         = RenderBody();
      ViewData["belowHeader"]        = RenderSection("BelowHeader", required: false);
      ViewData["bootomFixedContent"] = RenderSection("BootomFixedContent", required: false);
      ViewData["insideFooter"]       = RenderSection("InsideFooter", required: false);

      Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/Partials/body.Master.cshtml");
   }
   @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
   @{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/Partials/scripts.Master.cshtml"); }
</body>
</html>
```

I have a problem though.
With razon I can do this:

```
ViewData["belowHeader"] = RenderSection("BelowHeader", required: false); //Razor _Layout
```

And then paint the HtmlString inside the partial where the RenderSection should be.

```
var belowHeader = ViewData["belowHeader"] as HelperResult; //HelperResult contains the html string
@belowHeader //Inside the partial
```

But I don't know how to do the same thing within the .Master

```
var belowHeader = FindControl("BelowHeader").ToString(); //.Master (This doesn't work)
```

Any idea on how to solve this problem or another approach to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.